# commands in chatroom & defining words after command

Tags: javascript, php

Okay basically I'm trying to have a action happen of `alert('hi $message');` when a user enters the command `/command lewis` into the chatroom; In the alert I have stated the variable `$message` and this is the word followed by the command; for example `/command $message`. I have posted my script below; so basically what I'm trying to achieve is recognise when a user types `/command` followed by a $message into the `textarea` then perform an action.

**Chatroom Javascript**

```
        name ='<? echo $chat_room_username; ?>';


        $("#name-area").html("You are: <span>" + name + "</span>");


        var chat =  new Chat();
        $(function() {

             chat.getState(); 

             // watch textarea for key presses
             $("#sendie").keydown(function(event) {  

                 var key = event.which;  

                 //all keys including return.  
                 if (key >= 33) {

                     var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
                     var length = this.value.length;  

                     // don't allow new content if length is maxed out
                     if (length >= maxLength) {  
                         event.preventDefault();  
                     }  
                  }  
                                                                                                                                                                                                            });
             // watch textarea for release of key press
             $('#sendie').keyup(function(e) {   

                  if (e.keyCode == 13) { 

                    var text = $(this).val();
                    var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
                    var length = text.length; 

                    // send 

                    if (length <= maxLength + 1) { 

                        chat.send(text, name);  
                        $(this).val("");

                    } else {

                        $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));

                    }   


                  }
             });

        });

var instanse = false;
var state;
var mes;
var file;

function Chat () {
    this.update = updateChat;
    this.send = sendChat;
    this.getState = getStateOfChat;
}

//gets the state of the chat
function getStateOfChat(){
    if(!instanse){
         instanse = true;
         $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/rooms/process.php?room=<? echo $room; ?>",
               data: {  
                        'function': 'getState',
                        'file': file
                        },
               dataType: "json",

               success: function(data){
                   state = data.state;
                   instanse = false;
               },
            });
    }    
}

//Updates the chat
function updateChat(){
     if(!instanse){
         instanse = true;
         $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/rooms/process.php?room=<? echo $room; ?>",
               data: {  
                        'function': 'update',
                        'state': state,
                        'file': file
                        },
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(data){


                   if(data.text){

                       for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++) {

                        var newdata = data.text[i].replace(/:brand/g,"<img src=\"/_img/logo1.png\"></img>");
                            newdata = newdata.replace(/:tipsound/g,"<audio autoplay><source src=\"/tip.wav\" type=\"audio/mpeg\"></audio>");                    
                        <? 

                            $select_gifs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `submited_chatroom_gifs` WHERE `staff` = '1'");
                                while($gif = mysql_fetch_array($select_gifs)){ 

                        ?>
                                newdata = newdata.replace(/:<? echo $gif['name']; ?>/g,"<img data-toggle=\"tooltip\" height=\"<? echo $gif['height']; ?>\" width=\"<? echo $gif['width']; ?>\"title=\":<? echo $gif['name']; ?>\" src=\"/_img/gifs/<? echo $gif['img']; ?>\"></img>");

                                <? } ?>

                        $('#chat-area').append($("<p>"+ newdata +"</p>"));

                        }                       

                   }
                   document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;
                   instanse = false;
                   state = data.state;
               },
            });
     }
     else {
         setTimeout(updateChat, 1500);
     }


}

//send the message
function sendChat(message, nickname)
{       
    updateChat();
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/rooms/process.php?room=<? echo $room; ?>",
           data: {  
                    'function': 'send',
                    'message': message,
                    'nickname': nickname,
                    'file': file
                 },
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data){
               updateChat();
           },
        });
}
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
    $function = $_POST['function'];
    $room = $_GET['room'];

    $log = array();

    switch($function) {

         case('getState'):
             if(file_exists($room . '.txt')){
               $lines = file($room . '.txt');
             }
             $log['state'] = count($lines); 
             break; 

         case('update'):
            $state = $_POST['state'];
            if(file_exists($room . '.txt')){
               $lines = file($room . '.txt');
             }
             $count =  count($lines);
             if($state == $count){
                 $log['state'] = $state;
                 $log['text'] = false;

                 }
                 else{
                     $text= array();
                     $log['state'] = $state + count($lines) - $state;
                     foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
                       {
                           if($line_num >= $state){
                         $text[] =  $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line);
                           }

                        }
                     $log['text'] = $text; 
                 }

             break;

         case('send'):
          $nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
             $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
              $message = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['message']));
         if(($message) != "\n"){

             if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $message, $url)) {
                $message = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" target="_blank">'.$url[0].'</a>', $message);
                } 

             fwrite(fopen($room . '.txt', 'a'), "<p><font size=\"2px\">". $nickname . ": " . $message = str_replace("\n", " ", $message) . "</font></p>\n"); 
         }
             break;

    }

    echo json_encode($log);
}
?>
```

> the alert is only for the person who wrote the command in

Thankyou for any help, and I apologise for the lengthy question.

**[edit]** Sorry just re-read my question and I will just try and explain what I'm trying to achieve in abit more detail. So basically when a user inputs `/command lewis` the script would then perform an `alert('Hi Lewis');`. But then if a user was to enter `/command john` the alert would be `alert('Hi John');`.

The alert would be instead of posting the message to the chatroom.

Comment: Well, so what is actually the problem? is no alert showing up? is the wrong alert showing up? Does it have to be a valid username? Do you want this to be checking constantly for every key press, or will the user click / press enter?

Comment: i dont know how to create the function that would read what is posted and check to see if `/command` was wrote first and then I don't know how I would alert the word wrote after `/command` so for example `/command hello` instead of posting would alert `hello`

Comment: @Adjit I have edited my question to better reflect my goals

Comment: Well, as far as reading the data is concerned you can try and capture what the user is typing before moving that data into the chatroom box